# Java Caesar Cipher, use 2 keys

Tags: java, encryption

Encrypt the following phrase with the algorithm described for using two Caesar Cipher keys, with key1 = 8 and key2 = 21.

At noon be in the conference room with your hat on for a surprise party. YELL LOUD!

What is the encrypted string?

(Note: Your encrypted string should preserve spacing and punctuation.)

The original input is

At noon be in the conference room with your hat on for a surprise party. YELL LOUD!

The desired result is

io iwjv jz dv bcm kjvammmikz mwju edbc twpz pvb wi awm v ncmxmqnm xvzog. tmgt tjcy!

I am not able to write the correct Java code for this problem. Please help, thank you very much!

My code is

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class CaesarCipher {
    public String encrypt(String input, int key1, int key2) {
        //Make a StringBuilder with message (encrypted)
        StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder(input);
        //Write down the alphabet
        String checker = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String alphabet = checker.toLowerCase();
        //Compute the shifted alphabet
        String shiftedAlphabet1 = alphabet.substring(key1)+
        alphabet.substring(0,key1);
        String shiftedAlphabet2 = alphabet.substring(key2) + alphabet.substring(0,key2);
        //Count from 0 to < length of encrypted, (call it i)
        for(int i = 0; i < encrypted.length(); i+=2) {
            //Look at the ith character of encrypted (call it currChar)
            char currChar1 = encrypted.charAt(i);
            int j = i+1;
            char currChar2 = encrypted.charAt(j);
            //Find the index of currChar in the alphabet (call it idx)
            int idx1 = alphabet.indexOf(currChar1);
            int idx2 = alphabet.indexOf(currChar2);
            //If currChar is in the alphabet
            if(idx1 != -1){
                //Get the idxth character of shiftedAlphabet (newChar)
                char newChar1 = shiftedAlphabet1.charAt(idx1);
                encrypted.setCharAt(i, newChar1);

                char newChar2 = shiftedAlphabet2.charAt(idx2);
                encrypted.setCharAt(j, newChar2);
                }
                //Replace the ith character of encrypted with newChar

            }
            //Otherwise: do nothing
        }
        //Your answer is the String inside of encrypted
        return encrypted.toString();
    }
    public void testCaesar() {
        int key1 = 8;
        int key2 = 21;
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String messagechecker = 'At noon be in the conference room with your hat on for a surprise party. YELL LOUD!';
        String message = messagechecker.toLowerCase();
        String encrypted = encrypt(message, key1, key2);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        String decrypted = encrypt(encrypted, 26-key1,26-key2);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ? What was the problem ?

Comment: At Stack Overflow we help with specific programming problems with your own code. We will not write the code for you as this discourages you from learning. Please attempt the problem yourself, then show us your implementation. If you have specific problems with your code after that, then we can help you to solve them by giving you pointers.

Comment: Hi hi, just pasted my code above, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement: "(Note: Your encrypted string should preserve spacing and punctuation.)" is not handled by the code, in particular alphabet only contains lower case letters. You are going to need to handle all character code from 0x20 through 0x7f.

For "double" Caesar Cipher create a subroutine that performs a single Caesar Cipher on a string and than call that function first with the original input and the first key and then again with that output and the second key.

Answer (score 0):

i see the problem appears,when idx2 is greater than index of the for loop  (i.e j+1 > encrypted.length()). to compute idx2, u need to check the size of i+1(j).

```
if (i+1 < encrypted.length()) {
     int j = i+1;
     char ch2 = encrypted.charAt(j);
     char currChar2 = Character.toLowerCase(ch2);
     //Find the index of currChar in the alphabet (call it idx)
     int idx2 = alphabet.indexOf(currChar2);
        if (idx2 != -1) {
           char newChar2 = shiftedAlphabet2.charAt(idx2);
           //Replace the ith character of encrypted with newChar
           encrypted.setCharAt(j, newChar2);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//here is the complete correct answer

```
public class CaesarCipher {
//this method to encrypt a messgae using a key 
String encrypt (String input, int key){
 
// convert the original message to temp upper case letters  
String input2 = input.toUpperCase(); 
// using string builder rather than normal string
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(input2);
// default alphabet
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
// shiftted alphabet
String shifttedAlphabet= alphabet.substring(key)+alphabet.substring(0,key);

// iterating over the original message to get each char and then getting its index
// then getting the equilvent char in the shiftted alphabet
for (int i = 0; i <sb.length();i++){

char currentChar = sb.charAt(i);
int currentIndex = alphabet.indexOf(currentChar);

if (currentIndex != -1){
char shifttedChar = shifttedAlphabet.charAt(currentIndex);
sb.setCharAt(i,shifttedChar);
                       }
}
// converting the builder string to a normal string 
String encrypted = sb.toString();
// getting every char to its normal case even lower or upper
for (int i =0 ;i < input.length(); i ++){
boolean upper = Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i));
if(upper){sb.setCharAt(i,Character.toUpperCase(encrypted.charAt(i)));}
else {sb.setCharAt(i,Character.toLowerCase(encrypted.charAt(i)));}

}
// restting the encrypted message after editting to the lower nad upper case state
encrypted = sb.toString();
// returning the encrypted string 
return encrypted;
}

// this method to encrypt using two keys
String encryptTwoKeys (String input ,int key1 , int key2){
   String encryptedKey1= encrypt (input, key1); 
   String encryptedKey2= encrypt (input, key2); 
  
   StringBuilder finalEncrypted = new StringBuilder (input);
   
 
   
    for (int i = 0 ; i <encryptedKey1.length();i +=2){
    char currentChar = encryptedKey1.charAt(i);
     finalEncrypted.replace(i, i+1,String.valueOf(currentChar));
    
    
    }
   
    for (int i = 1 ; i <encryptedKey2.length();i +=2){
    char currentChar = encryptedKey2.charAt(i);
     finalEncrypted.replace(i, i+1,String.valueOf(currentChar));
    
    
    }
   
return finalEncrypted.toString();
}

void testEncryptTwoKeys(){
String encrypted = encryptTwoKeys("At noon be in the conference room with your hat on for a surprise party. YELL LOUD!", 8, 21);
System.out.println (encrypted);
String decrypted = encryptTwoKeys(encrypted, 26-8, 26-21);
System.out.println (decrypted);


}

void testEncrypt(){
FileResource fr = new FileResource();
String message = fr.asString();
String encrypted = encrypt(message, 15);
System.out.println("key is " +15+ "\n" + encrypted);

}
```

}

Comment: adding explanation to answer will help users.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class caesarCipher {
 
   /* This method is used to both encrypt and decrypt */

public static String encrypt(String input, int key1, int key2) {
    int pos = -1, pos1 = -1;
   
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; /* Take whole 
    alphabet as a string */
    
  /* modify the encrypted string use string builder */
   
   StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder(input);
  
         for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length(); i++) {
             /* take each character from the string */
        char sample = encrypted.charAt(i);
        /* We have to perform only with alphabet */
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(sample)) {
            /* check the position as key1 for even and key2 for odd position */
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                /*
                 * if the character is uppercase nothing to do
                 * cause we take alphabet in total uppercase
                 */
                if (Character.isUpperCase(sample)) {
                    /* find the position of the character from the alphabet */
                    pos = alphabet.indexOf(sample);
                    /* set the position as key */
                    pos = (pos + key1) % 26;
                    /* find the letter with updated position from the alphabet */
                    char res = alphabet.charAt(pos);
                    /* modify it */
                    encrypted.setCharAt(i, res);

                }
                /* if the character is in lowercase */
                else {
                    /* convert it to uppercase to find */
                    pos = alphabet.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(sample));
                    pos = (pos + key1) % 26;
                    char res = alphabet.charAt(pos);
                    /* convert the desired output in lowercase then modify it */
                    encrypted.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(res));

                }
                pos = -1;
            }
            /* same above procedure in case of odd position */
            else {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(sample)) {
                    pos1 = alphabet.indexOf(sample);
                    pos1 = (pos1 + key2) % 26;
                    char res1 = alphabet.charAt(pos1);
                    encrypted.setCharAt(i, res1);

                } else {
                    pos1 = alphabet.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(sample));
                    pos1 = (pos1 + key2) % 26;
                    char res1 = alphabet.charAt(pos1);
                    encrypted.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(res1));

                }
                pos1 = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return encrypted.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string:");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the key1:");
    int key1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the key2:");
    int key2 = sc.nextInt();
    /*
     * for both encryt and decrypt use the same method but for decrypt key will be
     * 26-key
     */
    String e = encrypt(input, key1, key2);
    System.out.println("...........After encryption...........\n" + e);
    String d = encrypt(e, (26 - key1), (26 - key2));
    System.out.println("...........After decryption...........\n" + d);
} 
        }
/* Compile and enjoy */
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).